# Tortoise SVN & Ankh/Visual SVN?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I recently acquired a new position and found that they had no Version Control.

I'll be spending most of my time in Visual Studio, and in the past I've used (pre-installed by previous companies) AnkhSVN and Visual SVN, and they all used Visual SVN as their SVN.

I would like to continue using either AnkhSVN or VisualSVN plugins for Visual Studio.  I'm trying to do this on the cheap, and I've had a little TortoiseSVN experience so I thought about going that way.

Question: If I install TortoiseSVN to a network drive, can I use AnkhSVN and/or VisualSVN Visual Studio plugins with it?   What other alternatives do you suggest if not?

I'm very comfortable using any number of SVN repositories, but I have heretofore never had to actually set one up for use with Visual Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Question: If I install TortoiseSVN to a network drive, can I use AnkhSVN and/or VisualSVN Visual Studio plugins with it? What other alternatives do you suggest if not?*

This is a two part question.

*Can I create SVN repository in network drive?*

Yes. Once you install TortoiseSVN on your local computer, creating SVN repository is just a matter of right-click and "Create Repository here"

*Can I use AnkhSVN and/or VisualSVN Visual Studio plugins with it?*

Yes. AnkhSVN or any other plugin is independent of where the repository is located. You need to configure the path.

Answer (score 0):

Creating SVN repository is very easy.
You can do that on the network drive.

If you explain for what you need it , it would be easier to recommend a good solution for you

There are several good free sites that let you place your code like:

1. [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
2. [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home)

   and there are more, some, like [assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home) also support Git which is good to know